# how to combine external css with index.html file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

using follwing fontowesome social media links and need draw a circle around social media logo. how can do this?

```
<ul class="social-media list-inline" align="right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube-play"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

I am going to select follwing css file

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on this? Also can you add in the css for those specific classes as well? Someone should be able to give you a working example.

Comment: see my edited question

Comment: Your ID is not referenced in the HTML you sent, also add in the css for the classes thats in the above code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.social-media li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a2e210f715.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="social-media">      
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube-play"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

By using `border-radius` and `padding` we can form a  circle around the icons.

Comment: Is this only you are expecting??

Comment: Its is the font-awesome CDN link

Comment: Font Awesome CDN is the easiest way to get icons on our web page.

Comment: now I need circle witch middle empty (like ring) how can do this?

Comment: Why did you take out the Facebook logo?

Comment: sorry bro, now I get the point. We can add CDN in multiple ways. I used script tag. I got this one to my email from http://fontawesome.io/. I had mentioned there my email address.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your file name.css">
</head>
```

wrap each

in a div with id circle 
it may get you your circle icons